# How to run Wireless Info Script without internet?

Tags: networking, network-manager

My Network Manager is broken, I don't have internet, what do I do? I don't know how to copy a file from Windows to Ubuntu (dualboot). I don't have USB stick.

In Windows WIFI works fine.

Comment: Do you have a CD and a CD-Burner?

Comment: If you start Ubuntu you can mount the NTFS-Drive of Windows. Then you can just copy Files to your running Ubuntu. You should see your Windows Drive in the FileManager of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows 8 or up then you need to do a complete shutdown in windows before mounting the drive in Ubuntu (if not you will get an error during mount), to do that press shift button while you click on shutdown in windows
then boot into Ubuntu and mount the required NTFS drive
Now to mount the drive:

1. `sudo fdisk -l` find the label of the partition
2. create a mount point `sudo mkdir /media/<MntName>`
3. mount the partition `sudo mount /dev/label /media/<MntName>` if it didn't work try `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/label /media/<MntName>`